# Redirect using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, redirect, location

I'm trying to redirect to another route using:

```
$location.path("/route");
```

But for some reason it is not working. I did an auto-complete widget using jQuery-UI and I'm calling a function from the scope once the user selects an option. I debugged it and it enters the function but it is never redirected to the other route. It only changes the route when I press a key.

I think it is kind of strange but I haven't figured out how to solve this. I used

```
window.location = "#/route";
```

and it works but I want to use the `path()` function.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

With an example of the not-working code, it will be easy to answer this question, but with this information the best that I can think is that you are calling the $location.path outside of the AngularJS digest.

Try doing this on the directive `scope.$apply(function() { $location.path("/route"); });`

Comment: Thank you very much and I'm sorry for not posting the not working example. But this was what my code needed.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work in of the .success method inside of an $http request? @Tomarto

Comment: on firefox (30~) console fires an error that $apply cycle is busy

Comment: How is this supposed to work? I am getting the following error:

Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at angular.js:78

..... hence, it is not working as windows.location = ''..

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg had the same question and just adding $scope.$apply(); just after $location.path("/route"); worked for me.

Answer (score 81):

Don't forget to inject `$location` into controller.

Comment: Nice catch - that was the problem for me.

Comment: Nice one, thank you for posting this, what seemed so obvious was not.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you're not using html5 routing, try `$location.path("route")`.
This will redirect your browser to `#/route` which might be what you want.

Answer (score 15):

If you need to redirect out of your angular application use `$window.location`. That was my case; hopefully someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Check your routing method:

if your routing state is like this

```
 .state('app.register', {
    url: '/register',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
      }
    }
  })
```

then you should use

```
$location.path("/app/register");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without knowing your code. My best guess is that the `onchange` event is not firing when you change your textbox value from JavaScript code.

There are two ways for this to work; the first is to call `onchange` by yourself, and the second is to wait for the textbox to lose focus.

Check [this question](/q/735462); same issue, different framework.