# how can I make a redirection with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a redirection to another route and the page have to be refreshed and treated server side, so the `$location.path(url)` can't help me. I have tried `window.location(url)` but I have this error: `window.location is not a function`

My app.js:

```
    'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/index'});
    $routeProvider.when('/logout', {
        controller: 'logoutCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

my logoutCtrl:

```
function logoutCtrl($scope, $location){
    $apply(function() { 
        $location.path("/users/logout"); 
    });
}
```

The partials/index contains this link:

```
a(href='/logout') Logout
```

Now I'm going to show how I manage my routes server side with Express.js:

```
app.get('/', ctrl.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', ctrl.partials);
app.get('/users/logout', ctrl.logout);

exports.logout = function(req, res)
{
  console.log('logout');
  req.session.destroy(function(err){ // I destroy my session
   res.redirect('/'); // redirection to '/'
  });
}
```

Now when I click on "logout" nothing happen, I'm just seeing this route `localhost:3000/logout` in my bar but if I type `localhost:3000/users/logout` I have the result expected (session destroyed and redirection to '/' )

Answer (score 4):

> With an example of the not working code will be easy to answer this question, but with this > information the best that I can think is that you are calling the $location.path outside of > the angularjs digest.
>
> Try doing this on the directive `scope.$apply(function() {$location.path("/route");});`"
>
> -[Renan Tomal Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908282/2872121)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm going to add my code to my previous post :)

Comment: its `$scope.$apply` or `scope.$apply`

Answer (score 0):

Just go with:

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

Alternatively:

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

which doesn't save the current page in browser session history.

Comment: This question has been asked in the context of AngularJS. It is never recommended to use non angular services in Angular e.g. $window is the Angular service. There are a number of reasons for that which might be irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the lecture. Replace window with $window and the answer still works.