# angular js redirect to view

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have below code

code to render /result content whenever the defaultview function is called using the $route service

```
angular.module('myapp').controller
    ('ResultController',['$route',function ($route){ this.defaultview=function(){$routes._ _ _ _  ('/result');};}
```

What will be the value in last line dash area?Any suggestions?

Comment: i think this is usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907961/redirect-using-angularjs

Comment: might be It's $location.path('/result')

Comment: OP, are you using angular-ui-router? If not, please remove the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $location if you are using ngRouter. i.e.

In your case, you can use

```
$location.path('/result');
```